# Populate the last selectbox based on the first

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I tried to populate a select box based on the first but no result, no error but the second select box is not populate:
My html:

```
               <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Firm:</label>
                        <select class="form-control marg-left-10" id="firm">
                            <?php if($all_firms): ?>
                                <?php foreach($all_firms as $firm): ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $firm['id_firm']; ?>"><?php echo $firm['name_firm']; ?></option>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Administrator</label>
                        <select class="form-control marg-left-10" id="admin">

                        </select>
              </div>
```

My php:

```
public function getAllFirms()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $all_firms = $this->db->query("SELECT *FROM firms");
    if ($all_firms->num_rows())
    {
        $all_firms = $all_firms->result_array();
    }
    else
    {
        $all_firms = NULL;
    }

    return $all_firms;

}
 public function getAdministrator($id)
{
    $this->load->database();
    $get_admin = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users,firms WHERE firms.id_firm = users.fk_firm and users.id = $id");
    if ($get_admin->num_rows())
    {
        $get_admin = $get_admin->result_array();
    }
    else
    {
        $get_admin = NULL;
    }

    return $get_admin;
}
```

My script:

```
    $("#firm").change(function() {
    var selectedMark = $("#firm").val();
    if (selectedMark != "") {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<?php echo base_url() . 'user/getAdministrator'; ?>" + selectedMark,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#admin").html("");
                $("#admin").append("<option value=''></option>");
                $.each(data, function() {
                    $("#admin").append("<option value='" + this.id + "'>" + this.name + "</option>");
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I use CodeIgniter as backend language, the first selectt box is populated but the second not.Please help me guys...HELP please!!!!! HELP ME GUYS!!Another idea to resolve this?

Comment: and your GET URL looks dodgeyt

Comment: I dont't understand the idea

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you've forgotten to add # when you calling 'admin' select. I.e. see 'success' section of your JS and change:

```
$('admin')...
```

to

```
$('#admin')...
```

Comment: You beat me too it! :(

Comment: Please also note that you did not target `#firm` for your `selectedMark` variable

Comment: I changed but not result

Answer (score 0):

```
you are looking like this:   
<div class="form-group">
 <label>Firm:</label>
 <select class="form-control marg-left-10" id="firm">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
 </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <label>Administrator</label>
 <select class="form-control marg-left-10" id="admin"></select>
</div>
<script>
$("#firm").change(function() {
var selectedMark = $("#firm option:selected").val();
var selectedMarkt = $("#firm option:selected").text();
if (selectedMark != "") {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "test.php",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#admin").append("<option value='" + selectedMark + "'>" + selectedMarkt + "</option>");
        }
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I need to pass url:<?php echo base_url() . 'user/getAdministrator'; ?>" + selectedMark,

Comment: <?php echo base_url() . 'user/getAdministrator'; ?> Its return the folder. can you say, which page the value going to pass?

Comment: public function getAdministrator($id)+ selectedMark

Comment: can you try this:
var dataString  = 'selectedMark='+ selectedMark;
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: <?php echo base_url() . 'user/getAdministrator'; ?>,
        data: dataString,

Comment: The url leave as it is url:<?php echo base_url() . 'user/getAdministrator'; ?>", The GET/POST values pass in dataString

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need another "/" on this line:

```
url: "<?php echo base_url() . 'user/getAdministrator'; ?>" + selectedMark,
```

Right after 'user/getAdministrator'.